# Command execution using paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am working on a python script which accepts a command to execute on remote linux. I surfed and found Paramiko. I developed a script which works fine if command like '**who**', '**ps**', '**ls**' is executed. But the same script failed to execute '**top**' and '**ping**' command.
Please help me out from this.

```
import paramiko
import sys

class sampleParamiko:
    ssh = ""
    def __init__(self, host_ip, uname, passwd):
        try:
            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.ssh.connect(host_ip, username=uname, password=passwd)
            #print "In init function"
        except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException) as e:
            print str(e)
            sys.exit(-1)

    def ececuteCmd(self,cmd):
        try:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            out_put = stdout.readlines()
            for item in out_put:
                print item,
        except paramiko.SSHException as e:
            print str(e)
            sys.exit(-1)
host_ip = "10.27.207.62"
uname = "root"
password = "linux"
cmd = str(raw_input("Enter the command to execute in the host machine: "))
conn_obj = sampleParamiko(host_ip, uname, password)
conn_obj.ececuteCmd(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the `invoke_shell()` method of `paramiko.SSHClient`.

From your code, you could do :

```
import paramiko
import sys

class sampleParamiko:
    ssh = ""
    def __init__(self, host_ip, uname, passwd):
        try:
            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.ssh.connect(host_ip, username=uname, password=passwd)
            #print "In init function"
        except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException,     paramiko.SSHException) as e:
            print str(e)
            sys.exit(-1)

    def ececuteCmd(self,cmd):
        try:
            channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell()
            timeout = 60 # timeout is in seconds
            channel.settimeout(timeout)
            newline        = '\r'
            line_buffer    = ''
            channel_buffer = ''
            channel.send(cmd + ' ; exit ' + newline)
            while True:
                channel_buffer = channel.recv(1).decode('UTF-8')
                if len(channel_buffer) == 0:
                    break 
                channel_buffer  = channel_buffer.replace('\r', '')
                if channel_buffer != '\n':
                    line_buffer += channel_buffer
                else:
                    print line_buffer
                    line_buffer   = ''
        except paramiko.SSHException as e:
            print str(e)
            sys.exit(-1)
host_ip = "10.27.207.62"
uname = "root"
password = "linux"
cmd = str(raw_input("Enter the command to execute in the host machine: "))
conn_obj = sampleParamiko(host_ip, uname, password)
conn_obj.ececuteCmd(cmd)
```

Output is :

```
Jean@MyDesktop:~$ ./test_paramiko.py 
Enter the command to execute in the host machine: ping -c2 127.0.0.1
ping -c2 127.0.0.1 ; exit 
[root@myserver ~]# ping -c2 127.0.0.1 ; exit 
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.032/0.037/0.043/0.008 ms
logout
```

But you cannot send commands interactively. So if you just `ping 127.0.0.1` it will go on forever, until you [CTRL]+[C] or kill your python script. Same for `top`.

If you want an interactive shell, have a look at the example scripts shipped with paramiko. Especially [demos/demo.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo.py) and [demos/interactive.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/interactive.py)